# fine uploader w/ cold-fusion upload the scaled images in different folder

Tags: coldfusion, fine-uploader

Hey guys i am stuck at a point .I have a situation where i need to upload the scaled image in different folder for example :- 1(small).jpg on small folder , 1(medium).jpg on medium folder and 1.jpg on uploads folder. Right now the code below is uploading all 3 images on different folders but the files are blob files.How to get the scaled image . (edited the code)

```
<cfset destinationDirectory = expandpath('/file_uploader/uploads')>
<cfset counter = 1>  
<cfset uniqueFileName = "">  
<cfset destinationFilePath = ""> 
<cfset smallfile = "">  
<cfset mediumfile ="">  
<cfset mainfile= ''>

<cfscript>
    variables.validMimeTypes =  {'image/jpeg': {extension: 'jpg'}
                                ,'image/png': {extension: 'png'}
                                ,'image/png': {extension: 'gif'}
                                }; </cfscript>


<cftry>     
    <cfset cnt= 1>  
    <cfset file_name = #qqfilename#>    
    <cfset file_size = #qqtotalfilesize#>

    <!--- If a file with the same name already exists at the destination --->
    <cfif fileExists(destinationDirectory & "/" & file_name)>

          <!--- Loop up to 100 times to try create a unique file_name --->

                <cfset destinationFilePath = destinationDirectory & "/" & counter & "_" & file_name>

          <!--- Loop up to 100 times to try create a unique filename --->
              <cfloop condition="counter LT 100">
                    <cfset destinationFilePath = destinationDirectory & "/" & counter & "_" & file_name>

                    <cfif fileExists(destinationFilePath)>
                          <cfset counter++>
                    <cfelse>
                          <cfset uniqueFileName = "IMG" & counter & "_" & file_name>
                          <cfbreak/>
                    </cfif>
              </cfloop>

    <!--- Filename does not already exist at the destination --->
    <cfelse>
          <cfset uniqueFileName = "IMG" & "_" & file_name>
          <cfset destinationFilePath = destinationDirectory & "/" & file_name>
    </cfif>
            <cfif len(trim(uniqueFileName))>
                    <cfset session.cntr ++>
                    <cfif  find("(small)",file_name) neq 0>
                        <cfset smallfile = file_name>
                        <cffile
                                action="upload"
                                destination="#UploadPath2#"
                                accept="#StructKeyList(variables.validMimeTypes)#"
                                nameconflict="#smallfile#"
                                >
                    <cfelseif find("(medium)",file_name) neq 0>
                        <cfset mediumfile = file_name>
                        <cffile
                                action="upload"
                                filefield="qqfile"
                                destination="#UploadPath1#"
                                accept="#StructKeyList(variables.validMimeTypes)#"
                                nameconflict="#uniqueFileName#"
                                >

                    <cfelse>
                        <cfset mainfile= file_name>
                        <cffile
                                action="upload"
                                filefield="qqfile"
                                destination="#destinationFilePath#"
                                accept="#StructKeyList(variables.validMimeTypes)#"
                                nameconflict="#uniqueFileName#"
                                >
                    </cfif>

                    <CFSET local.response['success'] = true >
                    <CFSET local.response['type'] = 'xhr' >
                    <CFSET local.response['obj'] = session.cntr >


            <cfelse>
                    <CFSET local.response['error'] = 'Unable to move the file and create a unique file_name at the destination'>
            </cfif>
    <cfoutput>
        #serializeJSON(local.response,true)#
    </cfoutput>          
    <cfabort/> 

<cfcatch type="any">     
    <cfoutput> #serializeJSON(session.cntr,true)# </cfoutput>
    <cfabort/>
</cfcatch> </cftry>
```

below is the UI page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <!-- jQuery
     ====================================================================== -->
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Fine Uploader Gallery CSS file
     ====================================================================== -->
     <link href="../file_uploader/includes/fine-uploader-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- Fine Uploader JS file
     ====================================================================== -->
     <script src="../file_uploader/includes/all.fine-uploader.js"></script>
    <script src="../file_uploader/includes/all.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../file_uploader/includes/jquery.fine-uploader.js"></script>
    <script src="../file_uploader/includes/jquery.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>



     <!-- Fine Uploader Gallery template
     ====================================================================== -->
     <script type="text/template" id="qq-template-gallery">

    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                 <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                 <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
             </div>
             <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                 <div>Upload a file </div>
             </div>
             <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
              <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
           <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
             </span>
             <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                 <li>
                     <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                     <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                         <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                     </div>
                     <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                     <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                         <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
                     </div>
                     <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                     <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                         <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                         Retry
                     </button>

                     <div class="qq-file-info">
                         <div class="qq-file-name">
                             <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                            <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                         </div>
                         <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                         <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                         <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                             <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                         </button>
                         <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                             <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                         </button>
                         <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                             <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                         </button>
                     </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>

             <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                 <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                 <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                     <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                 </div>
             </dialog>

             <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                 <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                 <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                     <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                     <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                 </div>
             </dialog>

             <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                 <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                 <input type="text">
                 <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
       <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                 </div>
             </dialog>
         </div>
     </script>

     <title>Fine Uploader Gallery View Demo</title> </head> <body>

     <!-- Fine Uploader DOM Element
     ====================================================================== -->
     <div id="fine-uploader-gallery"></div>

     <!-- Your code to create an instance of Fine Uploader and bind to the DOM/template
     ====================================================================== -->
     <script>       var posturl = "../file_uploader/upload_file.cfm";       var t= 0;
         var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
             element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
             //debug: true,
             autoUpload: false,
             template: 'qq-template-gallery',
             request:
             {
               // endpoint: '../file_uploader/upload_file.cfm?id=<cfoutput>#session.cntr#</cfoutput>'
                endpoint: posturl
             },
             thumbnails:
             {
                 placeholders:
                 {
                     waitingPath: '../file_uploader/includes/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                     notAvailablePath: '../file_uploader/includes/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                 }
             },
             validation:
             {
                 allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
             },

            callbacks:          {
                onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON , xhrOrXdr)
                {

                        if (responseJSON.success)
                        {
                             t++;
                         alert("success"+t);
                         uploadSuccess: {
                            endpoint: "../file_uploader/upload_file.cfm?id=1"
                                }
                        }
                },

                onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr)
                {
                    alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
                }
             },

             scaling:
             {
                //hideScaled: true,
                sizes:
                [
                    {name: "small", maxSize: 100},
                    {name: "medium", maxSize: 300}
                ]
             }

         });
     </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you don't need a loop to generate unique file names.  Appending a UUID or the results of a getTickCount() should do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the file name?

Comment: ...and @Dan is correct as well. Fine Uploader already gives you a uuid for each file. I'm not sure why you have elected to loop over the file name, adding a counter variable, until the name is "unique".

Comment: @raynicholus  <cfset file_name = #qqfilename#>    here i am getting the file name generated by Fine Uploader. But I am confused that where show i differentiate the image based on size and specify a the folder where they should upload.

Comment: Again, look at the file name to determine the size.

Comment: @ray please help , now i can specify the diffrent folder path, but i am getting 2 blob files of medium and small size. how to get the image small and medium

Comment: Step away from your code for now.  Type out the information you have available for each file.  Also type out the criteria for categorizing a file as large, medium, etc.  See if the information you have available allows you to cateorize the file according to your criteria.  If it does, code it.  If it doesn't either get more information or work on your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to determine the scaled size of an image. One way would be to look for the appropriate prefix in the image's file name. For example, if you've instructed Fine Uploader to include the phrase "small", then you should look for the string "(small)" in the file name server-side. The same goes for any other size prefix you have specified in [your scaling options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html).

Another option would be to look at the actual size of the files in a scaling group. Each scaled file in a group will contain a `qqparentuuid` request parameter pointing to the UUID of the original image/file. Once you have all of these files, you can examine their sizes to determine which one is small, medium, large, etc.

I highly suggest using the first option.

Comment: Is there any way to show only the small image and not the other scaled images ? Thank You